# mock testing without a custom hook react

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, mocking, automated-tests, react-testing-library

I've created a basic todolist component and am writing some tests for it but am wondering how i could mock test that local storage is gathering data with the code I currently have or whether I would need to create a custom hook to mock with. Ideally I would like to not have to do that, but feel like it would be the only way to use render hook.

```
This is my current code for todolist:
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Container, TextInput, Button, List } from '@mantine/core';
import { Tasks } from '../types';

const TodoList = () => {
  const [task, setTask] = useState('');
  const [todoList, setTodoList] = useState<Tasks[]>([]);

  const handleChange = (event: any): void => {
    setTask(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleDelete = (taskToDelete: any) => {
    const deleted = todoList.filter((t) => t.taskName !== taskToDelete);
    setTodoList(deleted);
    localStorage.setItem('localTasks', JSON.stringify(deleted));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (localStorage.getItem('localTasks')) {
      const storedList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('localTasks') || '{}');
      setTodoList(storedList);
    }
  }, []);

  const addTask = () => {
    const newTask = {
      taskName: task,
    };
    setTodoList([...todoList, newTask]);
    localStorage.setItem('localTasks', JSON.stringify([...todoList, newTask]));
    setTask('');
  };
  return (
    <Container>
      <TextInput
        type="text"
        name="task"
        placeholder="enter a task"
        onChange={handleChange}
        value={task}
      />
      <Button onClick={addTask} data-testid="add">
        Add Task
      </Button>
      {todoList.map((todo, key) => (
        <Container key={key}>
          <List
            data-testid="todos"
            icon={
              <Button
                onClick={() => {
                  handleDelete(todo.taskName);
                }}
              >
                X
              </Button>
            }
          >
            <List.Item>{todo.taskName}</List.Item>
          </List>
        </Container>
      ))}
    </Container>
  );
};

export default TodoList;
```

Updated code to add date id to todo:

```
import { Button, Container, List, TextInput } from '@mantine/core';
import type { ChangeEvent } from 'react';
import { useEffect, useLayoutEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';

const TodoList = () => {
  const isMounted = useRef(false);
  const [task, setTask] = useState('');
  const [todoList, setTodoList] = useState<Array<{ taskName: string; id: number }>>([]);

  const handleChange = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setTask(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleDelete = () => {
    setTodoList((prevTodoList) => prevTodoList.filter((todo, index) => index !== todo.id));
  };

  const addTask = () => {
    setTodoList((prevTodoList) =>
      prevTodoList.concat({
        taskName: task,
        id: new Date().getTime(),
      }),
    );
    setTask('');
  };

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    const localTasks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('localTasks') || '[]');
    if (localTasks.length > 0) setTodoList(localTasks);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isMounted.current) {
      localStorage.setItem('localTasks', JSON.stringify(todoList));
    } else {
      isMounted.current = true;
    }
  }, [todoList]);

  return (
    <Container aria-label="container">
      <TextInput
        type="text"
        name="task"
        placeholder="enter a task"
        onChange={handleChange}
        value={task}
      />
      <Button type="button" onClick={addTask} data-testid="add-todo" name="add-button">
        Add Task
      </Button>
      {todoList.map((todo, key) => (
        <Container key={key}>
          <List
            data-testid={`todo-${key}`}
            icon={
              <Button
                data-testid={`delete-todo-${todo.id}`}
                type="button"
                aria-label="delete-button"
                onClick={() => {
                  handleDelete(todo.id);
                }}
              >
                X
              </Button>
            }
          >
            <List.Item>{todo.taskName}</List.Item>
          </List>
        </Container>
      ))}
    </Container>
  );
};

export default TodoList;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, I'd recommend not mocking `localStorage` and instead testing it as is.

**TodoList.tsx**

```
import { Button, Container, List, TextInput } from "@mantine/core";
import type { ChangeEvent, ReactElement } from "react";
import { useEffect, useLayoutEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";

const TodoList = (): ReactElement => {
  const isMounted = useRef(false);
  const [task, setTask] = useState("");
  const [todoList, setTodoList] = useState<Array<{ taskName: string }>>([]);

  const handleChange = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void => {
    setTask(event.target.value);
  };

  // filter by index instead of by value (duplicate values can exist)
  // ideally you would use uniquely generated ids instead of by index
  const handleDelete = (key: number): void => {
    setTodoList((prevTodoList) =>
      prevTodoList.filter((_t, idx) => idx !== key)
    );
  };

  // concatenate new task into the todo list 
  // Array.concat() creates a new array
  const addTask = (): void => {
    setTodoList((prevTodoList) =>
      prevTodoList.concat({
        taskName: task,
      })
    );
    setTask("");
  };

  // on initial layout, update todo list if localTasks exist in localStorage
  useLayoutEffect((): void => {
    const localTasks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("localTasks") || "[]");
    if (localTasks.length > 0) setTodoList(localTasks);
  }, []);

  // on initial render, bypass updating local storage
  // on secondary/subsequent renders, update local storage with todoList
  useEffect((): void => {
    if (isMounted.current) {
      localStorage.setItem("localTasks", JSON.stringify(todoList));
    } else {
      isMounted.current = true;
    }
  }, [todoList]);

  return (
    <Container data-testid="container">
      <TextInput
        data-testid="task-input"
        type="text"
        name="task"
        placeholder="enter a task"
        onChange={handleChange}
        value={task}
      />
      <Button type="button" onClick={addTask} data-testid="add-todo">
        Add Task
      </Button>
      {todoList.map((todo, key) => (
        <Container key={key}>
          <List
            data-testid={`todo-${key}`}
            icon={
              <Button
                data-testid={`delete-todo-${key}`}
                type="button"
                onClick={() => {
                  handleDelete(key);
                }}
              >
                X
              </Button>
            }
          >
            <List.Item>{todo.taskName}</List.Item>
          </List>
        </Container>
      ))}
    </Container>
  );
};

export default TodoList;
```

**TodoList.test.tsx**

```
import { fireEvent, render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import TodoList from "./TodoList";

describe("TodoList", () => {
  it("renders without errors", () => {
    render(<TodoList />);

    expect(screen.getByTestId("container")).toBeInTheDocument();
  });

  it("adds a task to the list and stores it to localStorage", () => {
    render(<TodoList />);

    fireEvent.change(screen.getByTestId("task-input"), { target: { value: "123" } });

    fireEvent.click(screen.getByTestId("add-todo"));

    expect(screen.getByTestId("todo-0")).toBeInTheDocument();

    const localTasks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("localTasks") || "[]");
    expect(localTasks).toEqual([{ taskName: "123" }]);
  });

  it("removes a task from the list and removes it from localStorage", () => {
    render(<TodoList />);

    fireEvent.click(screen.getByTestId("delete-todo-0"));

    expect(screen.queryByTestId("todo-0")).not.toBeInTheDocument();

    const localTasks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("localTasks") || "[]");
    expect(localTasks).toEqual([]);
  });
});
```

**Results**

```
 PASS  src/TodoList.test.tsx
  TodoList
    ✓ renders without errors (82 ms)
    ✓ adds a task to the list and stores it to localStorage (23 ms)
    ✓ removes a task from the list and removes it from localStorage (10 ms)

--------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File          | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
--------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files     |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 TodoList.tsx |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                
--------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       3 passed, 3 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.073 s
```

Comment: Thank you for such an in depth resolution that seems as a better solution, this will give me some good review. And filtering by index makes a lot more sense.

Comment: How could I change the id to be date and delete by id preferably it would be good to avoid using key as I don't have control over its value. I have updated my code to where I am currently stuck on handleDelete function

Comment: You want to use something more unique, like a [uuid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) which you can find [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid). Then instead of passing back the `key`, you'll pass back the `id` and filter by it: `prevTodoList.filter((task) => task.id !== id)`

Comment: Looking at your edited code above, you're partially doing that, but you're not accepting the `id` as an argument of `handleDelete`. Update that callback to accept it as an argument: `const handleDelete = (id: string) => { ... }` and filter the task/todo by id (as shown in the above comment).